# Flexbox-Layout with Angular-Components

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I currently have a simple header, main, footer structure in my angular project and would like to make the main-component a flex-box in order to arrange all given components horizontally with equal width. Additionally I want to change the flex-direction, when the screen width is lower than 700px to column.
Since I already achieved this with pure HTML + CSS (see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aJPw7/443/) I have the feeling that this has something to do with angular parent components.

**Expected behaviour:** The two `<app-content-section>` elements each take 50% width of the `<app-main-component>` and 100% height. When I change the flex-direction to column they should have 100% width and 50% height:

**Currrent behaviour:** The `<app-content-section>` elements align when I use "justify-content" but are not influenced by any hight or width attributes.

Style.css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

app-root HTML:

```
<app-main-component>
    <app-content-section></app-content-section>
    <app-content-section></app-content-section>
</app-main-component>
```

app-main-component HTML:

```
<div class="main-component"> 
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

app-main-component CSS:

```
.main-component {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .main-component {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

app-content-section HTML:

```
<div class="content-section">
    <a>Test</a>
</div>
```

app-content-section CSS:

```
.content-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Edit1:** I also tried `:host{ }` but still no luck.

**Edit2:** I created another jsfiddle where I achieved the correct width, by styling the host-element and adding `flex: 1`, but elements still won´t use the whole height. https://jsfiddle.net/1c15q243/19/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the correct answer is adding a `:host{ flex: 1; }` in the "app-content-section CSS" in order to give its hosting-component `<app-content-section>` the correct flex-sizing.

I figured it out in the fiddle of my second edit, but @karthikaruna pointed out that I forgot to add HTML- tag in the stylig file.

Answer (score 1):

Set 100% height to `html`. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/q8c2wesu/1/) is the updated fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I pretty much found the solution myself, but forgot to add the HTML-tag in the styling. Works now perfectly.